# CDB crashes in Qt project

Tags: c++, qt

The riddle I am going to present to you just blowing my mind.
There is a project written on Qt 4.8.2, compiled by MSVC 2010 compiler, 32-bit application. It uses lapack linear algebra library and also some networking to download and present Google maps to the user. I'm not the author of the code: the author gave me source code as well as compiled application and my task is to adapt it to my purposes.

The application doesn't run on my Windows 7 Ultimate x64 system. More specifically, it runs but then hangs up showing no GUI, consuming 25% of CPU (i.e. one core) and the only way I can kill it is through Task Manager.

When I compile it in Qt Creator with MSVC2010 compiler and run under CDB - it crashes; the debugger's listing is presented below.

What is more - the application runs smmothly on my colleagues' computers as well as in the same Win7 system in the Virtual box. In client system the application runs but in the host system it hangs up! Re-installing the Win7 system didn't help: on the completely new system the situation repeated exactly.

Simple test application (doing nothing - just showing up a simple window) is being compiled and runs smoothly. The problem is only with that 'problem' application.

```
sStarting debugger 'CdbEngine' for ABI 'x86-windows-msvc2010-pe-32bit'...
dStart parameters: 'ZModel' mode: 1
dABI: x86-windows-msvc2010-pe-32bit
dExecutable: D:\trunk\build-Debug\ZModel.exe
dDirectory: D:\trunk\build-Debug
dDebugger: D:\Tools\WinDDK\Debuggers\cdb.exe
dProject: D:\trunk\src (built: D:\trunk\src)
dQt: d:\Tools\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2010
dQML server: 127.0.0.1:3768
dSysroot:
dDebug Source Loaction:
dSymbol file:
dDumper libraries:  d:\Tools\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\\qtc-debugging-helper\ D:\Tools\QtSDK\QtCreator\qtc-debugging-helper\258168559\ C:\Users\DAN\AppData\Local\Nokia\QtCreator\qtc-debugging-helper\258168559\
d
dDebugger settings:
dUseAlternatingRowColours: false  (default: false)
dFontSizeFollowsEditor: false  (default: false)
dUseMessageBoxForSignals: true  (default: true)
dAutoQuit: false  (default: false)
dLogTimeStamps: false  (default: false)
dVerboseLog: false  (default: false)
dCloseBuffersOnExit: false  (default: false)
dSwitchModeOnExit: false  (default: false)
dUseDebuggingHelper: true  (default: true)
dUseCodeModel: true  (default: true)
dShowThreadNames: false  (default: false)
dUseToolTips: false  (default: false)
dUseToolTipsInLocalsView: false  (default: false)
dUseToolTipsInBreakpointsView: false  (default: false)
dUseAddressInBreakpointsView: false  (default: false)
dUseAddressInStackView: false  (default: false)
dRegisterForPostMortem: false  (default: false)
dLoadGdbInit: true  (default: true)
dScriptFile:   (default: )
dWatchdogTimeout: 20  (default: 20)
dAutoEnrichParameters: false  (default: false)
dTargetAsync: false  (default: false)
dMaximalStackDepth: 20  (default: 20)
dAlwaysAdjustStackColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dShowStandardNamespace: true  (default: true)
dShowQtNamespace: true  (default: true)
dSortStructMembers: true  (default: true)
dAutoDerefPointers: true  (default: true)
dAlwaysAdjustLocalsColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dListSourceFiles: false  (default: false)
dSkipKnownFrames: false  (default: false)
dEnableReverseDebugging: false  (default: false)
dAllPluginBreakpoints: true  (default: true)
dSelectedPluginBreakpoints: false  (default: false)
dAdjustBreakpointLocations: true  (default: true)
dAlwaysAdjustBreakpointsColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dNoPluginBreakpoints: false  (default: false)
dSelectedPluginBreakpointsPattern: .*  (default: .*)
dBreakOnThrow: false  (default: false)
dBreakOnCatch: false  (default: false)
dBreakOnWarning: false  (default: false)
dBreakOnFatal: false  (default: false)
dAlwaysAdjustRegistersColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dAlwaysAdjustSnapshotsColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dAlwaysAdjustThreadsColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dAlwaysAdjustModulesColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dState changed from DebuggerNotReady(0) to EngineSetupRequested(1).
dQUEUE: SETUP ENGINE
dCALL: SETUP ENGINE
 Launching D:\Tools\WinDDK\Debuggers\cdb.exe -aqtcreatorcdbext.dll -lines -G -c .idle_cmd !qtcreatorcdbext.idle -y symsrv*symsrv.dll*C:\Users\DAN\AppData\Local\Temp\symbolcache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols D:\trunk\build-Debug\ZModel.exe
 using D:\Tools\QtSDK\QtCreator\lib\qtcreatorcdbext64\qtcreatorcdbext.dll of 22.07.2014 18:43:57.
 D:\Tools\WinDDK\Debuggers\cdb.exe running as 4444
 Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 CommandLine: D:\trunk\build-Debug\ZModel.exe
 Symbol search path is: symsrv*symsrv.dll*C:\Users\DAN\AppData\Local\Temp\symbolcache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
 Executable search path is:
 ModLoad: 00000000`012c0000 00000000`01c74000   ZModel.exe
 ModLoad: 00000000`77410000 00000000`775bb000   ntdll.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`775f0000 00000000`77770000   ntdll32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`73d90000 00000000`73dcf000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`73d30000 00000000`73d8c000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64win.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`73d20000 00000000`73d28000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64cpu.dll
 (130c.1300): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
 ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
 00000000`774c1220 cc              int     3
 cdb: Reading initial command '.idle_cmd !qtcreatorcdbext.idle'
 Execute when idle: !qtcreatorcdbext.idle
 0:000>
<l+t
<l+s
dNOTE: ENGINE SETUP OK
dState changed from EngineSetupRequested(1) to EngineSetupOk(3).
dQUEUE: SETUP INFERIOR
dState changed from EngineSetupOk(3) to InferiorSetupRequested(4).
dQUEUE: SETUP INFERIOR
dCALL: SETUP INFERIOR
<sxn 0x4000001f
<.asm source_line
<!qtcreatorcdbext.pid -t 0
 Source options are 1:
      1/t - Step/trace by source line
 Source options are 5:
      1/t - Step/trace by source line
      4/s - List source code at prompt
 Assembly options: source_line
 Qt Creator CDB extension version 0.11 (Qt 5 support) 64 bit built Oct 11 2011.
dTaking notice of pid 4876
dNOTE: INFERIOR SETUP OK
dState changed from InferiorSetupRequested(4) to InferiorSetupOk(6).
dState changed from InferiorSetupOk(6) to EngineRunRequested(7).
dQUEUE: RUN ENGINE
dCALL: RUN ENGINE
<sxe eh
<sxe ct
<sxe et
<g
dNOTE: ENGINE RUN AND INFERIOR RUN OK
dState changed from EngineRunRequested(7) to InferiorRunOk(11).
 ModLoad: 00000000`771f0000 00000000`7730f000   WOW64_IMAGE_SECTION
 ModLoad: 00000000`75880000 00000000`75980000   WOW64_IMAGE_SECTION
 ModLoad: 00000000`771f0000 00000000`7730f000   NOT_AN_IMAGE
 ModLoad: 00000000`77310000 00000000`7740a000   NOT_AN_IMAGE
 ModLoad: 00000000`75880000 00000000`75980000   C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`75450000 00000000`75496000   C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`6f250000 00000000`6f2c9000   D:\trunk\build-Debug\Solver.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`68e50000 00000000`690c6000   D:\trunk\build-Debug\QtCore4.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`75600000 00000000`75700000   C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`77130000 00000000`771c0000   C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`75370000 00000000`7537a000   C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`760f0000 00000000`7618d000   C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`75550000 00000000`755fc000   C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`76f30000 00000000`76fd0000   C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`75340000 00000000`75359000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`75700000 00000000`757f0000   C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`75160000 00000000`751c0000   C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`75150000 00000000`7515c000   C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`76fd0000 00000000`7712c000   C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`75ec0000 00000000`75ef5000   C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`75360000 00000000`75366000   C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`6f1e0000 00000000`6f249000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSVCP100.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`74e30000 00000000`74eef000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSVCR100.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`10000000 00000000`10580000   D:\trunk\build-Debug\lapack_win32_MT.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`00390000 00000000`00453000   D:\trunk\build-Debug\blas_win32_MT.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`76210000 00000000`7623a000   C:\Windows\syswow64\imagehlp.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`70e80000 00000000`72d3f000   D:\trunk\build-Debug\QtWebKitd4.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`68a00000 00000000`68e49000   D:\trunk\build-Debug\QtCored4.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`6f120000 00000000`6f1d7000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSVCP100D.dll
 ModLoad: 00000000`691d0000 00000000`69343000   D:\trunk\build-Debug\MSVCR100D.dll
 (130c.1300): Unknown exception - code c0000139 (first chance)
s
sException at 0x77671b12, code: 0xc0000139: DLL entry point not found, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) in ntdll32!LdrpSnapThunk
sProcess exited (3221225785)
eProcess crashed
eCDB crashed
dNOTE: ENGINE SPONTANEOUS SHUTDOWN
dState changed BY FORCE from InferiorRunOk(11) to EngineShutdownOk(22).
dState changed from EngineShutdownOk(22) to DebuggerFinished(23).
dQUEUE: FINISH DEBUGGER
dNOTE: FINISH DEBUGGER
dHANDLE RUNCONTROL FINISHED
sDebugger finished.
```

What could be done about this? How can I make application work? I've run out of ideas.
Because the Win7 system is clean - there are no Qt dlls in the Windows/System32 folder - nothing to delete.

Answer (score 0):

0xc0000139: DLL entry point not found - double-check that all needed dlls are there and of the proper kind *debug/release, 32/64 bit, whatever)